# <When> element below <Choose> element is unknown — why?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target, msbuild-15

I manually edited my MSBuild file to execute a few commands only when a certain condition is met:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  ...
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <Choose>
      <When Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)'!=''" >
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\intermediate" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(BaseOutputPath)" />
        <Message Text="Artifact files have been deleted." />
      </When>
    </Choose>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Yet, Visual Studio 2019 denies to load the `.vcxproj` file. There error message is:

> <When> element below <Choose> elements is unknown.

What did I do wrong here?

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2019 I was convinced that everything I did was by the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Choose element (MSBuild)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/choose-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) and note the parent elements. `Choose` cannot be used within a `Target`.

However, `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` will always be set with a value and `<When Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)' != ''" >` will always be true.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! I added this condition because I wanted to make sure after reading the warning of the [Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/delete-task?view=vs-2019) task: "You can easily delete the wrong files with expressions like `$(SomeProperty)\**\*.*` or `$(SomeProperty)/**/*.*`, especially if the property evaluates to an empty string".